# Angular 11 - An unhandled exception occurred: NGCC failed in pipeline build Cofiguration = production

Tags: angular, devops

I'm getting an error when compiled in prod !

```html
ng build --prod --configuration=production
Your global Angular CLI version (12.2.5) is greater than your local version (11.0.7). The local Angular CLI version is used.

To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".
Compiling @angular/animations : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/core : es2015 as esm2015
TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))
    at __read (D:\a\1\s\....\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:174:50)
    at Object.__spread (D:\a\1\s\...\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:193:28)
    at Renderer.renderAdjacentStatements (D:\a\1\s\...\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\rendering\renderer.js:159:63)
    at D:\a\1\s\...\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\rendering\renderer.js:80:52
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Renderer.renderFile (D:\a\1\s\...\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\rendering\renderer.js:76:46)
    at D:\a\1\s\....\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\rendering\renderer.js:53:84
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Renderer.renderProgram (D:\a\1\s\.....\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\rendering\renderer.js:48:54)
    at Transformer.transform (D:\a\1\s\....\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\packages\transformer.js:84:42)
An unhandled exception occurred: NGCC failed.
See "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-6jrO7O\angular-errors.log" for further details.
##[error]Process completed with exit code 127.
Finishing: build the angular app PRD.
```

it worked before! I haven't changed anything! locally it works without problem

```
package.json:
{
  "name": "angular",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^11.0.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^10.2.7",
    "@angular/common": "^11.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^11.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "^11.0.2",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^11.0.0-beta.33",
    "@angular/forms": "^11.0.2",
    "@angular/localize": "^11.0.2",
    "@angular/material": "^10.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^11.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^11.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "^11.0.2",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "bourbon": "^5.1.0",
    "bxslider": "^4.2.14",
    "c3": "^0.7.20",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.6.12",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "formdata-polyfill": "^3.0.20",
    "fuse.js": "^3.6.1",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "ng-lazyload-image": "^5.0.0",
    "ng-mat-search-bar": "^3.2.1",
    "ng-simple-slideshow": "^1.2.7",
    "ngx-pagination": "^3.2.1",
    "ngx-quill": "^13.0.1",
    "quill": "^1.3.7",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.3",
    "sass": "^1.29.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1100.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~11.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.0.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "~11.0.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: can you try with latest angular/cli globally. By installing npm i @angular/cli@12.2.5 -g. If problem persists I assume it is because of the 3rd packages you use.

Comment: Your CLI ng version is different from your local angular version that is also different from the cdk version. try to get them all to the same version first would be nice to be sure it's not coming from that.

Comment: @VugarAbdullayev which packages ?

Comment: try to remove 3d party packages one by one and see which causes it.

Comment: Thank you ,  is fixed, I changed the version of these two packages : npm install @angular/language-service@11.2.10 --save-dev
npm install @angular/compiler-cli@11.2.10 --save-dev